# Using Pandas groupby to calculate many slopes

Tags: pandas

Some illustrative data in a DataFrame (MultiIndex) format:

`|entity| year |value|
+------+------+-----+
|  a   | 1999 |  2  |
|      | 2004 |  5  |
|  b   | 2003 |  3  |
|      | 2007 |  2  |
|      | 2014 |  7  |`

I would like to calculate the slope using `scipy.stats.linregress` for each entity `a` and `b` in the above example. I tried using `groupby` on the first column, following the [split-apply-combine advice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), but it seems problematic since it's expecting one `Series` of values (`a` and `b`), whereas I need to operate on the two columns on the right.

This is easily done in R via `plyr`, not sure how to approach it in pandas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A function can be applied to a `groupby` with the `apply` function. The passed function in this case `linregress`. Please see below:

```
In [4]: x = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['a','a','b','b','b'],
                          'year':[1999,2004,2003,2007,2014],
                          'value':[2,5,3,2,7]})

In [5]: x
Out[5]: 
  entity  value  year
0      a      2  1999
1      a      5  2004
2      b      3  2003
3      b      2  2007
4      b      7  2014


In [6]: from scipy.stats import linregress

In [7]: x.groupby('entity').apply(lambda v: linregress(v.year, v.value)[0])
Out[7]: 
entity
a    0.600000
b    0.403226
```

Comment: This example works really well. How would you modify it if years were dates?


`x = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['a','a','b','b','b'],
                          'date':['1999-01-15','2004-01-15','2003-01-15','2007-01-15','2014-01-15'],
                          'value':[2,5,3,2,7]})

x['date'] = pd.to_datetime(x.date)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via the iterator ability of the group by object. It seems easier to do it by dropping the current index and then specifying the group by 'entity'.

A list comprehension is then an easy way to quickly work through all the groups in the iterator. Or use a dict comprehension to get the labels in the same place (you can then stick the dict into a pd.DataFrame easily).

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats

#This is your data
test = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['a','a','b','b','b'],'year':[1999,2004,2003,2007,2014],'value':[2,5,3,2,7]}).set_index(['entity','year'])

#This creates the groups
groupby = test.reset_index().groupby(['entity'])

#Process groups by list comprehension
slopes = [scipy.stats.linregress(group.year, group.value)[0] for name, group in groupby]
#Process groups by dict comprehension
slopes = {name:[scipy.stats.linregress(group.year, group.value)[0]] for name, group in groupby}
```

Comment: Note that the [0] on the end of the linregress says we are only interested in the first return parameter (slope). If you want all the return data, just delete the [0] and you'll get a list of tuples.