# Rolling Linear Fit with Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform a moving window linear fit to the columns in my dataframe.

```
n =5
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=n))
df['B'] = [1.9,2.3,4.4,5.6,7.3]
df['A'] = [3.2,1.3,5.6,9.4,10.4]

            B   A
2000-01-01  1.9 3.2
2000-01-02  2.3 1.3
2000-01-03  4.4 5.6
2000-01-04  5.6 9.4
2000-01-05  7.3 10.4
```

For, say, column B, I want to perform a linear fit using the first two rows, then another linear fit using the second and third rown and so on. And the same for column A. I am only interested in the slope of the fit so at the end, I want a new dataframe with the entries above replaced by the different rolling slopes.

After doing

```
df.reset_index()
```

I try something like

```
model = pd.ols(y=df['A'], x=df['index'], window_type='rolling',window=3)
```

But I get

```
KeyError: 'index'
```

EDIT: 
I aded a new column

```
df['i'] = range(0,len(df))
```

and I can now run

```
pd.ols(y=df['A'], x=df.i, window_type='rolling',window=3)
```

(it gives an error for window=2)

I am not understaing this well because I was expecting a string of numbers but I get just one result

```
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis---------------     

Formula: Y ~ <x> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         3
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   2

R-squared:         0.8981
Adj R-squared:     0.7963

Rmse:              1.1431

F-stat (1, 1):     8.8163, p-value:     0.2068

Degrees of Freedom: model 1, resid 1

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients--------------
Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         x     2.4000     0.8083       2.97     0.2068     0.8158     3.9842
 intercept     1.2667     2.5131       0.50     0.7028    -3.6590     6.1923
```

---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------

EDIT 2:
Now I understand better what is going on. I can acces the different values of the fits using

```
model.beta
```

Comment: don't you want: `model = pd.ols(y=df['A'], x=df.index, window_type='rolling',window=3)`

Comment: @EdChum I get Exception: Invalid RHS type: <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it out, but I don't think you need to specify the `window_type='rolling'`, if you specify the window to something, window will automatically be set to rolling.

[Source.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.3/computation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have problems doing this with the `DatetimeIndex` you created with `pd.date_range`, and find datetimes a confusing pain to work with in general due to the number of types out there and apparent incompatibility between APIs. Here's how I would do it if the date were an integer (e.g. days since 12/31/99, or years) or float in your example. It won't help your datetime problem, but hopefully it helps with the rolling linear fit part.

Generating your date with integers instead of datetimes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = range(1,6)
df['B'] = [1.9,2.3,4.4,5.6,7.3]
df['A'] = [3.2,1.3,5.6,9.4,10.4]

   date    B     A
0     1  1.9   3.2
1     2  2.3   1.3
2     3  4.4   5.6
3     4  5.6   9.4
4     5  7.3  10.4
```

Since you want to group by 2 dates every time, then fit a linear model on each group, let's duplicate the records and number each group with the index:

```
df_dbl = pd.concat([df,df], names = ['date', 'B', 'A']).sort()
df_dbl = df_dbl.iloc[1:-1] # removes the first and last row

   date    B     A
0     1  1.9   3.2 # this record is removed
0     1  1.9   3.2
1     2  2.3   1.3
1     2  2.3   1.3
2     3  4.4   5.6
2     3  4.4   5.6
3     4  5.6   9.4
3     4  5.6   9.4
4     5  7.3  10.4
4     5  7.3  10.4 # this record is removed

c = df_dbl.index[1:len(df_dbl.index)].tolist()
c.append(max(df_dbl.index))
df_dbl.index = c

   date    B     A
1     1  1.9   3.2
1     2  2.3   1.3
2     2  2.3   1.3
2     3  4.4   5.6
3     3  4.4   5.6
3     4  5.6   9.4
4     4  5.6   9.4
4     5  7.3  10.4
```

Now it's ready to group by `index` to run linear models on `B` vs. `date`, which I learned from [Using Pandas groupby to calculate many slopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907133/using-pandas-groupby-to-calculate-many-slopes). I use `scipy.stats.linregress` since I got weird results with `pd.ols` and couldn't find good documentation to understand why (perhaps because it's geared toward datetime).

```
1    0.4
2    2.1
3    1.2
4    1.7
```